# OSX compiling openalpr errors on make

Tags: macos, opencv, openalpr

Trying to compile openalpr for OSX, get errors:

> [ 62%] Building CXX object
>   misc_utilities/CMakeFiles/openalpr-utils-classifychars.dir/classifychars.cpp.o
>   /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:207:31:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_ONE'
>             else if (waitkey == ENTER_KEY_ONE || waitkey == ENTER_KEY_TWO)
>                                 ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:207:59:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_TWO'
>             else if (waitkey == ENTER_KEY_ONE || waitkey == ENTER_KEY_TWO)
>                                                             ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:340:21:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_ONE'   while (waitkey
>   != ENTER_KEY_ONE && waitkey != ENTER_KEY_TWO && waitkey != ESCAPE_KEY)
>                       ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:340:49:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_TWO'   while (waitkey
>   != ENTER_KEY_ONE && waitkey != ENTER_KEY_TWO && waitkey != ESCAPE_KEY)
>                                                   ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:367:29:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_ONE'
>           waitkey = (int16_t) ENTER_KEY_ONE;
>                               ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:380:18:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_ONE'   if (waitkey ==
>   ENTER_KEY_ONE || waitkey == ENTER_KEY_TWO)
>                    ^ /Users/dd/Documents/opencv/openalpr/src/misc_utilities/classifychars.cpp:380:46:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENTER_KEY_TWO'   if (waitkey ==
>   ENTER_KEY_ONE || waitkey == ENTER_KEY_TWO)
>
> 7 errors generated. make[2]: ***
>   [misc_utilities/CMakeFiles/openalpr-utils-classifychars.dir/classifychars.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 make[1]: ***
>   [misc_utilities/CMakeFiles/openalpr-utils-classifychars.dir/all] Error
>   2 make: *** [all] Error 2

On 10.10.5.
Used brew for successful openalpr install:
`homebrew/science/openalpr: stable 2.2.0 (bottled), HEAD`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i am able to successfully compile after an edit to 'classifychars.cpp'. Seems to be executing ok, so here is what i did someone else runs into the same issue.

Below is the original block of code starting at line 40:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
const int LEFT_ARROW_KEY = 2;
const int RIGHT_ARROW_KEY = 3;

const int DOWN_ARROW_KEY = 1;
const int UP_ARROW_KEY= 0;

#elif WIN32
const int LEFT_ARROW_KEY = 2424832;
const int RIGHT_ARROW_KEY = 2555904;

const int DOWN_ARROW_KEY = 2621440;
const int UP_ARROW_KEY = 2490368;

const int ENTER_KEY_ONE = 13;
const int ENTER_KEY_TWO = 10;
```

Added the 2 'undeclared identifiers' in the OSX section:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
const int LEFT_ARROW_KEY = 2;
const int RIGHT_ARROW_KEY = 3;

const int DOWN_ARROW_KEY = 1;
const int UP_ARROW_KEY= 0;

const int ENTER_KEY_ONE = 13;
const int ENTER_KEY_TWO = 10;

#elif WIN32
const int LEFT_ARROW_KEY = 2424832;
const int RIGHT_ARROW_KEY = 2555904;

const int DOWN_ARROW_KEY = 2621440;
const int UP_ARROW_KEY = 2490368;

const int ENTER_KEY_ONE = 13;
const int ENTER_KEY_TWO = 10;
```